# Fresh Debian install with Hyper-V doesn't go into DE unless manually instructed

Tags: linux, debian, hyper-v, kde

I have installed a fresh Debian on a virtual machine created in Hyper-V. I have selected to install KDE environment and usually, there's no problem with it since the system always loads straight into DE. Not in this case though.

In this case, the system starts into a black login screen with the terminal input.

[image: terminal login screen]

It prompts to login and to enter the password, which it successfully accepts. After that, I have all the freedom in the world to do anything I want from the terminal. I can even enter the KDE desktop if I manually enter `startx` command.

I have no idea, what causes such behavior. I searched around for a solution, such a thing mainly happens when you have several DEs or none, but KDE is my only one. And the system seems to be completely intact, installed from an official ISO.

When I tried to install a new log in screen, I got a network error and then system settings suddenly crashed with the following log:

```
Application: System Settings (systemsettings5), signal: Segmentation fault
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f4c646d1cc0 (LWP 1404))]

Thread 13 (Thread 0x7f4c2a0e5700 (LWP 1420)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6  0x00007f4c681c2b84 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5
#7  0x00007f4c681c1c49 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5
#8  0x00007f4c69527072 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007f4c69f114c1 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#10 0x00007f4c69f18970 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#11 0x00007f4c694fd489 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#12 0x00007f4c6950046b in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x00007f4c6954f103 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0x00007f4c66c51f2e in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00007f4c66c521c8 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#16 0x00007f4c66c5225c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#17 0x00007f4c6954e727 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#18 0x00007f4c694fc15b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#19 0x00007f4c6934be76 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#20 0x00007f4c69355a67 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#21 0x00007f4c678effa3 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#22 0x00007f4c690474cf in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 12 (Thread 0x7f4c2b2eb700 (LWP 1418)):
#0  0x00007f4c69038494 in read () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f4c66c97aa0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f4c66c51c0f in g_main_context_check () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f4c66c520e0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f4c66c5225c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007f4c6954e743 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007f4c694fc15b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007f4c6934be76 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f4c69355a67 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007f4c678effa3 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x00007f4c690474cf in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 11 (Thread 0x7f4c3c848700 (LWP 1417)):
#0  0x00007f4c6903c819 in poll () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f4c66c52136 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f4c66c5225c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f4c6954e743 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007f4c694fc15b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f4c6934be76 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007f4c69355a67 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007f4c678effa3 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#8  0x00007f4c690474cf in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 10 (Thread 0x7f4c3daee700 (LWP 1415)):
#0  0x00007f4c6903c819 in poll () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f4c66c52136 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f4c66c5225c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f4c6954e743 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007f4c694fc15b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f4c6934be76 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007f4c68763c65 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#7  0x00007f4c69355a67 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f4c678effa3 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#9  0x00007f4c690474cf in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 9 (Thread 0x7f4c3e2ef700 (LWP 1414)):
#0  0x00007f4c69038494 in read () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f4c66c97aa0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f4c66c51c0f in g_main_context_check () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f4c66c520e0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f4c66c524c2 in g_main_loop_run () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007f4c3eed3266 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007f4c66c7a415 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#7  0x00007f4c678effa3 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#8  0x00007f4c690474cf in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 8 (Thread 0x7f4c3eaf0700 (LWP 1413)):
#0  0x00007f4c66c97a93 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#1  0x00007f4c66c51c0f in g_main_context_check () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f4c66c520e0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f4c66c5225c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f4c66c522a1 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007f4c66c7a415 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007f4c678effa3 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x00007f4c690474cf in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 7 (Thread 0x7f4c4a088700 (LWP 1412)):
#0  0x00007f4c66c9be84 in g_mutex_unlock () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#1  0x00007f4c66c51b09 in g_main_context_check () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f4c66c520e0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f4c66c5225c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f4c6954e743 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f4c694fc15b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007f4c6934be76 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007f4c68763c65 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#8  0x00007f4c69355a67 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007f4c678effa3 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x00007f4c690474cf in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 6 (Thread 0x7f4c4b765700 (LWP 1411)):
#0  0x00007f4c66c9be69 in g_mutex_lock () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#1  0x00007f4c66c5196f in g_main_context_check () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f4c66c520e0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f4c66c5225c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f4c6954e743 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f4c694fc15b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007f4c6934be76 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007f4c68763c65 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#8  0x00007f4c69355a67 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007f4c678effa3 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x00007f4c690474cf in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 5 (Thread 0x7f4c5a5a1700 (LWP 1409)):
#0  0x00007f4c678f600c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f4c5af6651b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
#2  0x00007f4c5af66397 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
#3  0x00007f4c678effa3 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00007f4c690474cf in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 4 (Thread 0x7f4c5ada2700 (LWP 1408)):
#0  0x00007f4c678f600c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f4c5af6651b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
#2  0x00007f4c5af66397 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
#3  0x00007f4c678effa3 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00007f4c690474cf in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f4c616c7700 (LWP 1407)):
#0  0x00007f4c69054fe2 in clock_gettime () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f4c6954e061 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#2  0x00007f4c6954c899 in QTimerInfoList::updateCurrentTime() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#3  0x00007f4c6954ce95 in QTimerInfoList::timerWait(timespec&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007f4c6954e4be in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f4c66c51669 in g_main_context_prepare () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007f4c66c5206b in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#7  0x00007f4c66c5225c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#8  0x00007f4c6954e743 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007f4c694fc15b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007f4c6934be76 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x00007f4c697a4545 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#12 0x00007f4c69355a67 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x00007f4c678effa3 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#14 0x00007f4c690474cf in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f4c636f3700 (LWP 1406)):
#0  0x00007f4c6903c819 in poll () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f4c678b0cf7 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#2  0x00007f4c678b291a in xcb_wait_for_event () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#3  0x00007f4c6428ed79 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#4  0x00007f4c69355a67 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f4c678effa3 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007f4c690474cf in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f4c646d1cc0 (LWP 1404)):
#0  0x00007f4c678f600c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f4c678b0f02 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#2  0x00007f4c678b263f in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#3  0x00007f4c678b2752 in xcb_wait_for_reply () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#4  0x00007f4c6428da5a in QXcbConnection::sync() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#5  0x00007f4c642aeb33 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#6  0x00007f4c642aec10 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#7  0x00007f4c69acdbe3 in QBackingStore::beginPaint(QRegion const&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#8  0x00007f4c69f20846 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#9  0x00007f4c69f20e19 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#10 0x00007f4c69f379d5 in QWidgetPrivate::syncBackingStore() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#11 0x00007f4c69f4f608 in QWidget::event(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#12 0x00007f4c69f114c1 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#13 0x00007f4c69f18970 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#14 0x00007f4c694fd489 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#15 0x00007f4c6950046b in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#16 0x00007f4c6954f103 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#17 0x00007f4c66c51f2e in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#18 0x00007f4c66c521c8 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007f4c66c5225c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007f4c6954e727 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#21 0x00007f4c64325491 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#22 0x00007f4c694fc15b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#23 0x00007f4c6a0fbedd in QDialog::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#24 0x00007f4c4806e7bf in KNS3::DownloadDialog::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5NewStuff.so.5
#25 0x00007f4c480fe10f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kcm_sddm.so
#26 0x00007f4c69526933 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#27 0x00007f4c69ff7602 in QAbstractButton::clicked(bool) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#28 0x00007f4c69ff781a in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#29 0x00007f4c69ff8bdf in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#30 0x00007f4c69ff8db5 in QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#31 0x00007f4c69f4f4d8 in QWidget::event(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#32 0x00007f4c69f114c1 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#33 0x00007f4c69f18bb8 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#34 0x00007f4c694fd489 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#35 0x00007f4c69f17ee9 in QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(QWidget*, QMouseEvent*, QWidget*, QWidget*, QWidget**, QPointer<QWidget>&, bool) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#36 0x00007f4c69f69fd4 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#37 0x00007f4c69f6cb5e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#38 0x00007f4c69f114c1 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#39 0x00007f4c69f18970 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#40 0x00007f4c694fd489 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#41 0x00007f4c69940003 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::MouseEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#42 0x00007f4c69941e85 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#43 0x00007f4c6991c07b in QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#44 0x00007f4c6432549b in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#45 0x00007f4c694fc15b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#46 0x00007f4c69504132 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#47 0x00005575a030f5aa in ?? ()
#48 0x00007f4c68f7209b in __libc_start_main () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#49 0x00005575a030f62a in _start ()
[Inferior 1 (process 1404) detached]
```

Can you help me to solve this? I don't want to manually start KDE every time I launch the system.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command as root:

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

It will change the default boot target to the graphical environment. It's an equivalent of `runlevel 5` in System V nomenclature.

To revert this, you would set `multi-user.target`.

Comment: I entered the command as root as you recommended, but the system still loads into the core screen. I have updated the image to show what happens after I enter login and password.